# Grub not detecting Windows disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual-boot setup, with Linux Mint 19.3 and Windows 10 each installed on a separate disk. Windows says that it is installed in a "Legacy/BIOS mode", and so I used this mode to install Linux as well. The installer detected the Win bootloader correctly, but after the installation there was no Windows entry in  GRUB and no method of fixing this I found online has worked for me. I can boot into Win by using the BIOS menu, Win works fine, and so does Linux.

Here's my boot repair summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PV79583Jtc .
And either I am not using boot-repair correctly or it doesn't help in my case, I've tried numerous combinations of settings and none worked.

I assume that there is something that I'm missing/have configured wrong, but I'd like to find out what that is, instead of just bruteforcing a system-reinstall...

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try running sudo update-grub.  That works on Ubuntu.  Although, I don't know anything about EFI, so that might also be your issue.

Comment: Did that already, didn't work I'm afraid

Comment: I'm out of my knowledge zone here, but I heard that UEFI machines have a directory for boot information.  The UEFI is a newer replacement for BIOS, but that's about all I know.  Try searching for EFI.  Maybe that will shed some light.  Also try Unix & Linux, since Mint is off topic on askUbuntu, I think.  https://unix.stackexchange.com